# How to maintain session timeout for long period in asp.net mvc4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session-timeout

I have done some modifications in Web.config and globals.asax file giving some extra time limit, but the session is not working for the given time. Sometimes getting expired very soon.

Web.config:

```
 <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="60000"/>

 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="28880"/>
 </authentication>
```

Global.asax/session_start():

```
 Session.Timeout = 1200;
```

I added namespaces for the session wherever required, but still the session problem persists, session is stateless after all coding is done.

Please can anyone suggest a proper solution, or if my flow is ambiguous, please let me know how to do it in a standard manner.

Thanks. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are providing timeout in 2 different places I mean u need to provide timeout either in web.config or in global.asax file so better remove timeout declaration from global.asax..

as documeneted here http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/10/session-timeout-problem-in-aspnet.html :-

> By default our websites session timeout is 20 mins after that session
>   will gets expire suppose if we want to set our custom timeout in our
>   applications we can set it in different ways (web.config, global.asax
>   and in IIS)
>
> Check below methods to set session timeout in web.config, global.asax
>   and in iis
>
> In Web.config file we can set session timeout like as shown below

```
<configuration>
> 
> <system.web>
> 
>  <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60">
> 
>  </sessionState>
> 
>  </system.web>
> 
> </configuration>
```

> In  Global.asax file we can set session timeout in Session_Start event
>   like this

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
> 
> {
> 
> // Code that runs when a new session is started
> 
> Session.Timeout = 15;
> 
> }
```

> If you set session time out in both web.config and in your iis the iis
>   session out value overrides web.config session time out

Answer (score 0):

If above solution doesn't work than remove

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms timeout="50"/>
```

from web.config file

Comment: Could you explain why this will help? Also you should link to the answer you're referring to because it will not always be above yours. (Click 'share' to get a link.)